# Mid-2010s Kernel Panic GPU - best options?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, kernel-panic, gpu

I'm having issues with kernel panics on a mid-2010 Macbook Pro 15 inch. I have read many threads about this ([What's the cause of GPU panics on macbook pro mid 2010?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114238/whats-the-cause-of-gpu-panics-on-macbook-pro-mid-2010)) and the thread that links to are good examples. The panics seem to be related to GPU/especially video for me. Mavericks made them less frequent, but they didn't go away.

Apple was able to tell me that the logic board has already been replaced (before the computer came into my hands, presumably as part of the extended warranty that was intended to fix this problem).

Given the age of my computer, I'm wondering what my best options are. Is a new graphics card certain to fix the problem? If so, is it best to send it to Apple or to try to order one and install it myself?

Answer (score 1):

Suggested problem tracing /and repair) steps (after each test the performances).

- Vacuum clean the inside of your Mac to improve cooling.
- Google and Install gfxCardStatus, Leave on Dynamic Switching. From there it will Monitor and Alert you to what apps switch you to the Nvidia Graphic Card.
- Also open the Activity monitor - Energy tab, where you can see when the Nvida card kicks in, and does it switch on/off irregularly.
- Monitor your Console log for irregular (fast)GPU switching.
- Do some [hardware testing](http://www.geeks3d.com/gputest/):

> GpuTest is a cross-platform (Windows, Linux and Max OS X) GPU stress
>   test and OpenGL benchmark. GpuTest comes with several GPU tests
>   including some popular ones from Windows'world (FurMark or TessMark).

This test might help you decide to replace the card.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a macbook pro mid 2010, affected by this issue. After a long search, i thin i found a workaround to avoid pay a lot of money for an old laptop repair (no warranty).
This issue is avoid the mac to use the nvidia chip, yes i know, you lost this funcionallity, but u get one stable equipment.

As super user (sudo su -) go to /System/Library/Extensions
Move the files/directories named NV*.kext and GeForce*.kext to a new backup directory.
Reboot the system.

in my case me laptop doesn't reboot or GPU panic for 5 days.

I hope this help others.
Good luck frm Spain.

Comment: After rebooting, I could not anymore log in, mouse movements were extremely slow and delayed, and the screen had a strange episodic horizontal line refresh pattern. It was considerably difficult to boot again (by a cloned HD) and restore /System/Library/Extensions/ to its previous state. On the basis of this experience, I would discourage trying the trick suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the Logic board was not an option for me and neither was it financially feasible. I have answered the question here:
[Question about GPU Panic on Mid 2010 MacBookPro6,2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179825/question-about-gpu-panic-on-mid-2010-macbookpro6-2/304525#304525)

We have a permanent software solution, and I think folks are going to be happy with it.